# clean restart during reshaping raid 5 to raid 6, is it possible to retrieve something? or continue the grow?

Tags: partitioning, raid, mdadm

everything is in the title. I have to specify that the restart wasn't initiated by me.
The command was : sudo mdadm --grow /dev/md227 --level=6 --raid-devices=7 --backup-file=/root/raid5backup

I have read [here](http://www.spinics.net/lists/raid/msg40771.html)
that it wasn't catastrophic if it was a clean shutdown.
here is the state of the RAID now:

```
/dev/md227:
        Version : 1.2
     Raid Level : raid0
  Total Devices : 7
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

          State : inactive

      New Level : raid6
     New Layout : left-symmetric
  New Chunksize : 512K

           Name : DOCKER-BATCAVE:227
           UUID : 837da647:3c4431c9:607feb30:b887f4fd
         Events : 1901220

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice

       -       8      176        -        /dev/sdl
       -       8       17        -        /dev/sdb1
       -       8       33        -        /dev/sdc1
       -       8       49        -        /dev/sdd1
       -       8       65        -        /dev/sde1
       -       8       81        -        /dev/sdf1
       -       8      113        -        /dev/sdh1
```

What should I do? or What can I do?  Re create a raid 5 on the 6 original disc to hope to retrieve some files? Or --grow--continue will work? how do I indicate to the grow continue to use the backup-file already created ?

thanks for any help you could provide

EDIT: I forgot to say that the raid was managed with LVM.
EDIT: sorry for the multiple EDIT but the event didn't occur when I was busy with server.

Comment: Do I have to assemble the RAID first ? and the a grow continue ? or should I just do --grow --continue --backup-file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I had to `mdadm --stop array`
and then reassemble with `mdadm --assemble array --backup-file /location`